# ¿como detener un clip.loop? JAVA

Tags: java

pues es simple, tengo una función la cual reproduce un sonido en loop, cuando recibe como parametro true, la idea es que cuando esa función reciba como parametro false, el sonido se detenga,
he probado usando el stop, mas sin embargo esto no detiene el loop, dejo mi codigo:

```
 public void alarm(boolean seguir) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, IOException{
  Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();
    
    if(seguir){
    
         sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("alarm/sonido.wav")));
        sonido.start()/*loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)*/;
        sonido.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        
    }else{
    
        sonido.stop();
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Por lo que podran notar, soy extremadamente novato,
agradecería sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

El objeto sonido debe estar afuera del método:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();

    public void alarm(boolean seguir) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, IOException {

        if (seguir) {
            sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("alarm/sonido.wav")));
            sonido.start()/*loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)*/;
            sonido.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

        } else {
            sonido.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {

        Test t = new Test();
        t.alarm(true);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        t.alarm(false);

    }


    public Test() throws LineUnavailableException {
    }

}
```